# Can't remove/delete symlink

Tags: linux, unix, symbolic-link

I have tried to create a symlink and it threw this error:

```
ln: accessing `.test': Permission denied
```

Now I can't unlink or delete the symlink file.

Tried Googling for help but could not find a solution.

Please find the results of following commands.

```
stat .test : 

  File: `.test'stat: cannot read symbolic link `.test': Permission denied

  Size: 26          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 16384  symbolic link
Device: 1fh/31d Inode: 312075453   Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (11160/ chatt)   Gid: (11307/  pgr)
Access: 2012-11-12 11:36:51.167327500 +0000
Modify: 2012-11-12 11:36:51.163331700 +0000
Change: 2012-11-12 11:36:51.163331700 +0000
 Birth: -

chattr -i .test:
chattr: Permission denied while trying to stat .test

lsatter .test
lsattr: Operation not supported While reading flags on .test
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I have found a solution for this matter. The problem was that, I have created this symlink from a mounted remove storage to a local file. Some how I assume that the remote storage does not support symlinks. How ever I was able to SSH to the remote storage server and then delete the file. I cant post this as an answer yet but I will do so after 7 hours past from the time I have posted the question. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this matter. The problem was that, I have created this symlink from a mounted remove storage to a local file. Some how I assume that the remote storage does not support symlinks. How ever I was able to SSH to the remote storage server and then delete the file. I cant post this as an answer yet but I will do so after 7 hours past from the time I have posted the question. thanks.